# maven-surefire-report-plugin 2.8 error: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.sink.SiteRendererSink.unknown

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

My project started to fail during the execution of `mvn site:site` since I updated the maven-surefire-report-plugin to version 2.8, which was just [released a week or so ago](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg117227.html).

Here is the exception:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.sink.SiteRendererSink.unknown(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/maven/doxia/sink/SinkEventAttributes;)V
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.sink.SiteRendererSink.unknown(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/maven/doxia/sink/SinkEventAttributes;)V
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.surefire.report.SurefireReportGenerator.doGenerateReport(SurefireReportGenerator.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.surefire.report.SurefireReportMojo.executeReport(SurefireReportMojo.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.maven.agent.ComponentInterceptor.invoke(ComponentInterceptor.java:47)
    at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor$3.invoke(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:229)
    at $Proxy7.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor.executeMojo(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:165)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:165)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:688)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Here is the relevant section of my pom file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8/version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Switching back to version 2.7.2 results in no error.  Anyone knows more about this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-714

> As can be seen from
>   http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/
>
> "Note: As of version 2.8 this plugin
>   requires Maven Site Plugin 2.1 or
>   higher to work properly. Version 2.7.2
>   and older are still compatible with
>   newer surefire versions, so mixing is
>   possible."
>
> For all practical purposes you can
>   stay on 2.7.2 as long as you want,
>   since the xml format used for
>   interchange will stay backward
>   compatible (newer surefire versions
>   can use older
>   surefire-report-plugins). You will, of
>   course, be missing out on bugfixes in
>   reporting if you choose to not upgrade
>   reporting-plugin/site.

If you don't have the maven-site-plugin mentioned in your pom it won't pull in the latest version.  Add it as specified in http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/plugin-info.html